# Error: Program type already present: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Base64Variant

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

When I compile my code I get this exception:

com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Base64Variant

I know I should probably exclude some transitive dependencies but I don't know how to do it

These are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

The code worked well until i added these lines :

```
 ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode responseNode= null;

            try {
                responseNode = mapper.readTree(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            assert responseNode != null;
            int SUCCESS = responseNode.get("success").asInt();
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), SUCCESS, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And i get 4 errors :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Base64Variant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution to that problem; i was just adding the library jackson-core in my libs folder. I deleted it, so, now it works.